# Infopath 2013 Data Connection Wizard to Sharepoint 2013 - The operation could not be completed (already have and using root site)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I'm having problem when trying to create a new data connection to my sharepoint 2013 sites from Infopath 2013. It says "**The operation could not be completed**".

Have read from the forums and all around the internet about the issue, and everyone is suggesting to make sure that we have an active site at the root.
Well, **I have a root site**, and in fact, **I am using the root '/' for my main sharepoint site since the beginning**. So, this is not the cause of my problem.

The **site is normally working**, no problem seen. I **can open it from browser normally using hostnames, IP**, etc. All **available infopath forms in it still working normally**.

The **problem is when I try to create a new data connection** since a week ago. Before, everything was normal, I can create any data connection to my sharepoint normally. And when I edit my already established data connection, no problem at all.

So the problem, I think, purely lays on the 'create new data connection wizard'.

Any one can help me with this issue? I think some other people also experiencing this, but still no solution found.

Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Central Administration.
1) Click on Application Management.
2) Click on View all site collections and select the web application from the drop down check whether the root site collection is available http://serverName:12345.
3) If the root site is not available then click on Application Management and then 4) click on Create site collection that is available under Site Collections.
5) Create the root site and then try to create a new connection in the InfoPath form; you will be able to create it successfully.